# Azure Test Plans: Track Manual Tests across multiple projects

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

Azure Devops Server Test plans: Is there any way to record manual Test case work items for the same product on separate projects to make them easier to relate/query?

I could modify the test case work item to include a product name, thus enabling creation of a query over all projects for a single product. Is the better way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following methods:

1. Similar to as you have mentioned, you can add a same tag to all the of the Test cases for the same product. For example, you can use the product name as the tag. Then you can create a query to filter these Test cases across projects. For more details, see "[**Query across or within projects**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#query-across-or-within-projects)".
2. Another method you can try is to link all these Test cases for the same product with a same parent work item (such as an **`User Story`**). Then you can track and view all these Test cases under this parent. For more details, see "[**Link user stories, issues, bugs, and other work items**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/add-link?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser)".